# Why Platform Version 9.2 is not displayed in Appium UI tool

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios

I downloaded the appium dmg file in order to have the appiumm interface, but I'm wondering why the values 9.2 are not displayed in the Platform Version dropdown

Version 1.4.13 (Draco)

[[image: iOS Settings[1]]

Comment: You should be able to type whatever iOS version you want into the box. I think those are just default values for what Appium supports, though. Not necessarily versions of iOS simulator that you currently have installed.

Comment: Thanks @econoMichael, you are right. Thanks for you answer

Comment: @econoMichael if you add an answer, I will upvote it. This helped me. Thanks.

Comment: @AutonomousApps happy to help. Sure I'll make my answer official.

Answer (score 2):

The dropdown box is editable. You can add whatever iOS version you'd like. Just keep in mind to have the appropriate version of Xcode installed and if necessary, to manually install that iOS simulator, also.